# R not producing a figure in jupyter (IPython notebook)

Tags: r, windows-8, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am very excited about using python and R together and tried using R in Jupyter (ipython notebbok), however, I could not generate figures in the R kernel.

The error message shown below is displayed when I try to plot figures. I highly appreciate your help.

I am using Anaconda and windows 8.

```
x<-1:10
plot(x)
```

> Error in png(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, bg, res, type = "cairo", : unable to load winCairo.dll: was it built?
>
> Error in jpeg(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, quality, bg, res, type = "cairo", : unable to load winCairo.dll: was it built?

The following is displayed in the Anaconda command prompt:

> Unable to load 'C:/Users/aa/Anaconda/R/library/grDevices/libs/x64/winCairo.dll'

Comment: Can you add the commands you used to install `IRKernel`?

Comment: I used the following commands to install IRKernel.                               conda install -c r r                                                                                   conda install -c r r-irkernel

Comment: It seems that this package has some quirks. I get a `seqfault` when I install it on my mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution from the post on this [group](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/GS-pD6FMovI).

Solution I did:

I had the most release of R (R 3.2.0) and following the discussion in the above link, I installed R 3.1.3 and copied winCairo.dll from C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\library\grDevices\libs\x64  to C:\Anaconda\R\library\grDevices\libs\x64.

Copying winCairo.dll from R 3.2.0 does not work for my case.

With this, it plots a figure but with an error message that says "Error in replayPlot(obj): invalid graphics state"

Then, thanks to this [link](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/113),
I added 'options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')' and it works fine.

[image]

options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')

x=1:10

plot(x)

[image]

Comment: Facing the same issue on redhat system. are there any solutions for linux.